# Border input[type=radio]:checked для ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Пытаюсь сделать выбор цвета с помощью radio input, в верстаемый шаблон выбор цвета происходит по кусочку образца... я не знаю как объяснить посмотрите: http://jsfiddle.net/2xH8k/

Так вот, цвет рамки образца в ie8 не меняется когда мы выбираем определенный radio, хотя в остальных браузерах все нормально, помогите поправить? Желательно без js выкрутасов...

Comment: без js не обойтись, ie8 не поддерживает этот псевдокласс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь без js в ie8 не обойтись, он не знает что такое :checked

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [http://selectivizr.com/](http://selectivizr.com) —  добавляет `IE` возможность работать с  новыми полезным селекторам `:checked`, `nth-*()` и т.д.

Размер сжатой — 4кб.

Comment: Спасибо, большое, но уже не актуально. Решил вопрос с применением js